# Group and sort array

Tags: javascript

I have data that is coming from the server like this

```
let value = [
  {
   'commongId': 1,
   'principal': true,
   'creationDate': '2019-11-03:40:00'
   },
  {
   'commongId': 2,
   'principal': false,
   'creationDate': '2017-10-25T01:35:00'
   },
  {
   'commongId': 2,
   'principal': true,
   'creationDate': '2019-05-25T08:00:00'
   },
  {
   'commongId': 1,
   'principal': false,
   'creationDate': '2018-11-25T09:40:00'
   },
  {
   'commongId': 1,
   'principal': false,
   'creationDate': '2017-11-25T09:40:00'
   },
   {
    'commongId': 2,
    'principal': false,
    'creationDate': '2018-05-25T08:00:00'
    },
]
```

I want to transform it in a way that the courses are grouped by `commonId`, and that the principal course of each 'id' should appear first, and the rest of the courses belonging to the same `commonId` come after that principal course sorted by the creation date (asc).

So basically the output should be

```
let value = [
    {
        commongId: 1,
        principal: true,
        creationDate: '2019-11-03:40:00'
    },
    {
        commongId: 1,
        principal: false,
        creationDate: '2017-11-25T09:40:00'
    },
    {
        commongId: 1,
        principal: false,
        creationDate: '2018-11-25T09:40:00'
    },
    {
        commongId: 2,
        principal: true,
        creationDate: '2019-05-25T08:00:00'
    },
    {
        commongId: 2,
        principal: false,
        creationDate: '2017-10-25T01:35:00'
    },


    {
        commongId: 2,
        principal: false,
        creationDate: '2018-05-25T08:00:00'
    }
];
```

I have a working solution, which in my opinion looks horrible and too complicated.

```
// function to group the the courses by commonId
const groupBy = (data, keyFn) =>
    data.reduce((agg, item) => {
        const group = keyFn(item);
        agg[group] = [...(agg[group] || []), item];
        return agg;
    }, {});

let transformedValue = groupBy(courses, item => item.commonId);
//removing the keys from the array of objects
transformedValue = Object.keys(transformedValue).map(k => transformedValue[k]);
// sorting each inner array by creationDate
transformedValue = transformedValue.map(el => {
    let modified = el.sort((a, b) =>
        moment(a.creationDate).diff(moment(b.creationDate))
    );
    // pushing the principal object of each array to the top
    const foundIndex = modified.findIndex(element => element.principal);
    if (foundIndex > -1) {
        const foundElement = modified.find(element => element.principal);
        modified.splice(foundIndex, 1);
        modified.unshift(foundElement);
    }
    return modified;
});
// flattening the array to one level
transformedValue = transformedValue.flat();
// using the transformed value in the subscription
of(transformedValue).subscribe(p => {
    this.dataToShow = p;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sort` like this.

```js
const value=[{commongId:1,principal:true,creationDate:"2019-11-03:40:00"},{commongId:2,principal:false,creationDate:"2017-10-25T01:35:00"},{commongId:2,principal:true,creationDate:"2019-05-25T08:00:00"},{commongId:1,principal:false,creationDate:"2018-11-25T09:40:00"},{commongId:1,principal:false,creationDate:"2017-11-25T09:40:00"},{commongId:2,principal:false,creationDate:"2018-05-25T08:00:00"},];

value.sort((a, b) => a.commongId - b.commongId 
                    || b.principal - a.principal 
                    || a.creationDate.localeCompare(b.creationDate)
           )

console.log(value)
```

- The array will first be sorted based on `commongId`. If both have the same `commongId`, the subtraction will return 0. So, `||` will check the next expression because `0` is [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.
- Then, it will be sorted based on `principal`. You can subtract 2 boolean values because it returns 1, -1 or 0 based on the value.

  ```
  true - false === 1
  false - true === -1
  true - true === 0
  ```
- If they still have the same value for `commongId` and `principal`, the array will be sorted based on the `creationDate`. Since the dates are in the ISO format, you can do a string comparison using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). If the date is in some other format, you could do

  ```
  new Date(a.creationDate) - new Date(b.creationDate)
  ```

Comment: hmm, when I run this in my sample, I get those with `principal: true` always first.. could it be because my commonId is actually not just a number like I showed in the example above, but it's actually a uuid?

Comment: @AngularDebutant that's because `a.commongId - b.commongId ` is probably returning NaN. So, boolean comparison is proffered. `a.commongId - b.commongId` only works for numbers or booleans. You need to apply a similar compare logic for `uuid` such that it returns a postive or negative number.

Comment: @AngularDebutant What is the type of `uuid`? Is it a string?

Comment: yes sir! I used `localCompare` for the `uuid` and it seems to work

Comment: can you please show me how I can do so that the group of `commonId` with the principal having the lower `creationDate` goes first? So in this case those with `commonId === "2"` should come first. The rest of the sorting should stay the same.

Comment: @AngularDebutant the order of each expression in the `compareFunction` decides the priority of each object in the array. If your primary sorting logic is `creationDate`, you can move `a.creationDate.localeCompare(b.creationDate)` expression to the beginning of the `||` operator. This will sort the array of objects chronologically. If the 2 items have the same `creationDate`, then the `||` will look at the next expression in the function

Comment: yes that's what I understood, but I have tried so hard and no result :(

Comment: could you post the expected result in a jsfiddle? I couldn't understand the requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203316/discussion-between-angulardebutant-and-adiga).

Comment: I sent you a message in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs map and lodash groupBy.

```
of(response).pipe(
   map(response => _groupBy(moveToFirst(response, item => item.principal === true)), 'commonId')
);
```

Where `moveToFirst` is a custom method to move  the required item to Index 0.

Comment: Well the thing is that this `moveToFirst` needs to happen after grouping! because I need to move the object to the beginning of each group with the same commonId.